# REST Api for Infinite scrolled query results

Tags: performance, rest, http

I'm building an internal server which contains a database of customer events.   The webpage which allows access to the events is going to utilize an infinite scroll/dynamic loading scheme for display of live events as well as for browsing the results of queries to the database.   So, you might query the database and maybe get 200k results.   The webpage would display the 'first' 50 and allow you to scroll and scroll and scroll to see more and more results (loading perhaps 50 more at time).

I'm supposed to be using a REST api for the database access (a C# server).   I'm unsure what the API should be so it remains RESTful.   I've come up with 3 options.  The question is, are any of them RESTful and which is most RESTful(is there such a thing -- if not I'll pick one of the RESTful).

#### Option 1.

- `GET /events?query=asdfasdf&first=1&last=50`

This simply does the query and specifies the range of results to return.   The server, unable to keep state, would have to requery the database each time (though perhaps utilizing the first/last hints to stop early) the infinite scroll occurs.   Seems bad and there isn't any feedback about how many results are forthcoming.

#### Option 2 :

- `GET /events/?query=asdfasdf`
- `GET /events/details?id1=asdf&id2=qwer&id3=zxcv&id4=tyui&...&id50=vbnm`

This option first does a query which then returns the list of event ids but no further details.  The webpage simply has the list of all the ids(at least it knows the count). The webpage holds onto the event id list and as infinite scroll/dynamic load is needed, makes another query for the event details of the specified ids.   Each id is would nominally be a guid, so about 36 characters per id (plus &id##= for 41 characters).   At 50 queries per hit, the URL would be quite long, 2000+ characters.  The URL limit mentioned elsewhere on SO is around 2k.   Maybe if I limit it to 40 ids per query this would be fine.   It'd be nice to simply have a comma separated list instead of all the query parameters.    Can you make a query parameter like `?ids=qwer,asdf,zxcv,wert,sdfg,rtyu,gfhj, ... ,vbnm` ?

#### Option 3 :

- `POST /events/?query=asdfasdf`
- `GET /events/results/{id}?first=1&last=50`

This would post the query to the server and cause it to create a results resource.   The ID of the results resource would be returned and would then be used to get blocks of the query results which in turn contain the event details needed for the webpage.   The return from the POST XML could contain the number of records and other useful information besides the ID.  Either the webpage would have to later delete the resource when the query page closed or the server would have to clean them up once they expire (days or weeks later).

I am concerned at Option 1, while RESTful is horrible for the server.  I'm not sure requesting so many simultaneous resources, like the second GET in Option 2 is really RESTful or practical(seems like there has to be a better way).  I'm not sure Option 3 is RESTful at all or if it is, its sort of cheating the REST thing by creating state via a POST(or should that be PUT).

Comment: For what its worth.  We discussed it internally and decided on option 3.   Within the server, I have hang onto the query cursor for a 'reasonable' amount of time and thus avoid creating/updating a table or something to save the results.   I still have misgivings about it being restful (or not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 3 worked out fine.   It required the server to maintain the query results and there was a bit of debate about how many queries (from various users) should simultaneously be saved as there would be no way to know when a user was actually done with a query.